# Powershell restore previous version of the files

Tags: powershell, restore

We got hit by virus, it changed all common file extension to .kmybamf (.txt >> .txt.kmybamf ) and if I delete .kmybamf , the file got damaged.....

So I made a list of all files that got damaged. now I'm trying to overwrite them by previous version. Anyone knows how to do it in Powershell?

I can do it in cmd similar to this

```
subst X: \localhost\D$\@GMT-2011.09.20-06.00.04_Data
robocopy Z: D:\Folder\ /E /COPYALL
```

But I want to do it in one shot in Powershell, It has to be a "if .kmybamf found, then restore previous version." and powershell seems like has no such cmdlet for restoring previous version of files or folders.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileList = Get-Content -Path "\\localhost\D$\@GMT-2011.09.20-06.00.04_Data"
$destinationFolder = "D:\Folder\"

foreach ($file in $fileList)
{
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $destinationFolder -Force
}
```

This will also work but I find it less readable

```
Get-Content -Path "\\localhost\D$\@GMT-2011.09.20-06.00.04_Data" | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "D:\Folder" -Force }
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this. but the "source" and "destination" are not fixed. so it must be wherever i found "".kmybamf" then do restore.

Comment: Can you add an extract of your .kmybamf file list to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content is for reading the text from the files, to read the files from a folder you would have to use Get-Childitem